# Is there a command to pause the native Ubuntu sound player?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, vlc, rhythmbox

So under my volume drop down menu, I have Spotify, Rhythmbox and VLC:

[image]

Here I can pause and play the various different applications. My question is, is there a command to pause the one that is currently playing, e.g. I could set up a short cut to pause whichever was playing. This is mainly because Spotify doesn't have command options as far as I can tell, and I would like to pause it using blue proximity when I get up?

Comment: The lack of a universal command to pause/play the currently playing media player annoyed me enough that I wrote a python script to do just that. I put it on Github. Here is the link: https://github.com/mel00010/OmniPause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you need command-line access, you can talk to it directly over DBUS. Here's an example I stole from [Fran Diéguez](http://www.mabishu.com/blog/2010/11/15/playing-with-d-bus-interface-of-spotify-for-linux/):
>
> To pause:
>
> ```
> dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Pause
> ```
>
> Or to toggle:
>
> ```
> dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause
> ```
>
> For more commands, see the [MPRIS2 Player specifications](http://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/latest/Player_Interface.html).

Taken from [Oli's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/492366/186134) to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492361/are-there-commands-to-control-the-spotify-for-linux-preview-e-g-pause) question.